# How to integrate Apple VPP to MDM, Looking for VPP API refrences

Tags: mdm, apple-vpp

All,

I have been looking for VPP api reference to integrate VPP in our MDM solution. To link VPP to MDM it is required to donwload VPP token from VPP account and upload it MDM server and MDM server use this code to get further details from VPP account. But I am not getting any clue how to do that?

Please share any reference to API or Documentation related to VPP integration to MDM.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPP documentation is part of MDM documentation. There is a whole chapter (35 pages) dedicated to it.

Comment: Where can I get it? I tried search on google and failed to find it. If you can help me find it?

Comment: You can find it here (https://developer.apple.com/downloads). Type "MDM" in search. However you will need to be in Enterprise Developer program to get access to it.

Comment: Thanks Victor for your help

Comment: that document seems to have disappeared / been renamed.  I found this one to be useful and covers the same info mentioned above: https://images.apple.com/business/docs/VPP_Business_Guide.pdf